# Show results from an Eclipse Plugin

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I developed a simple Eclipse Plugins that adds a menu on my toolbar.
The corresponding handler searches for files on a given (by an InuptDialog) directory. Now I want to show these results inside eclipse himself.
I need something simple, I wouldn't create a whole view for this, a simple tab with a TextEdit or a List of items inside it would be OK.

Which way you think is the simplest and easier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to show something in the Eclipse window you **must** use a view or an editor.

A view is quite simple to write, one of the examples when create a new plug-in will create an example view.

You could also show the results in a dialog.